# Insert data into MySql using Asp.Net in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to insert data into Mysql database using Asp.net in C# but it's generating the following error:

You have an error in SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax to use near 'values ('First name', 'Surname', 'Mobile Number', 'Email Address', 'Password')'. I have one more field in my signup form that is confirm password but I don't want to store it into my database. Here is what I am doing:

```
String connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully connected to database");
            String queryString = "insert into signup_table(first_name,surname,mobile_number,email_address,password," +
                                 "values (@F_Name, @S_Name, @M_Number, @E_Address, @Password)";
            command = new MySqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@F_Name", FirstN_TextBox.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_Name", SurN_TextBox.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@M_Number", MobileN_TextBox.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_Address", EmailA_TextBox.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",Password_TextBox.Text);
                command.ExecuteReader();
connection.Close();
```

Thanks in Advance... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed a bracket. It should be the following:

```
String queryString = "insert into signup_table(first_name,surname,mobile_number,email_address,password) " +
                     "values (@F_Name, @S_Name, @M_Number, @E_Address, @Password)";
```

Comment: You are right. Sorry about that and thanks for your time. It's always a silly mistake. Now its working fine... :)

Answer (score 0):

You must replace ',' with ')' after password column name.

Comment: You are right. Sorry about that and thanks for your time. It's always a silly mistake... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a string for the insert query, like so:

```
 String queryString = "insert into 
 signup_table(first_name,surname,mobile_number,email_address,password) +
 values (@F_Name, @S_Name, @M_Number, @E_Address, @Password)";
```